Canonical correlation analysis via svd
For my own understanding I'm trying to reproduce the canonical correlation results from R CCA::cc using crossproduct and svd. I tried a few things but cannot get it right, can you offer any insight?
This is the code using the CCA package:
library(CCA)
data(nutrimouse)
X=as.matrix(nutrimouse$gene[,1:10])
Y=as.matrix(nutrimouse$lipid)

X <- scale(X) # A 40x10 matrix scaled and centered
Y <- scale(Y) # A 40x21 matrix scaled and centered

res.cc <- cc(X,Y)

I've tried:
cp <- crossprod(X, Y)
cca_svd <- svd(cp)

What should I do now to get canonical correlations and coefficients for the X and Y matrices?
ChatGPT gives the following, but it doesn't seem right:
cp <- crossprod(X, Y)

# Step 2: Perform SVD on the crossproduct
cca_svd <- svd(cp)

# Step 3: Calculate canonical correlations
# The canonical correlations are the singular values from SVD
canonical_correlations <- cca_svd$d^2 / (1 + cca_svd$d^2)  # Adjusted for canonical correlation

# Step 4: Calculate canonical variables
# The canonical variables can be obtained from U and V matrices
U <- cca_svd$u
V <- cca_svd$v

# Canonical variates
canonical_variates_X <- X %*% U
canonical_variates_Y <- Y %*% V

For example, the canonical correlations from ChatGPT are:
canonical_correlations
 [1] 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.99 0.99 0.93 0.85 0.77

while CCA::cc from above gives:
res.cc$cor
 [1] 0.99 0.98 0.94 0.92 0.81 0.72 0.64 0.61 0.55 0.36

